# How to loop this?

Tags: c#

Im having trouble learning how to loop, and Im stuck on how to do this. Basically I was asked to program that rolls a 6 sided die and it'll ask you how many times you want to roll it. Based on how many times you roll, it will out put a table of how many times it landed on each side. This is what I have so far.

```
using System;

namespace Dice
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            bool continueRunning = true;
            int sessionNumber = 1;

            DisplayInstructions();

            while (continueRunning)
            {
                int howMany = int.Parse(getInfo("How many times do you want to roll the die?"));
                Dice aDice = new Dice();
                aDice.RollDice();

                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("Session Number: {0}", sessionNumber);
                Console.WriteLine(aDice);

                continueRunning = getYorN("Would you like to run again?");
                sessionNumber++;
                Console.Clear();
            }
        }

        public static bool getYorN(string question)
        {
            bool validInput = false;            

            while (!validInput)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}", question);
                Console.WriteLine("Enter 'yes' or 'no' to continue...");
                string userResponse = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
                if (userResponse == "yes" || userResponse == "no")
                {
                    validInput = true;
                    switch (userResponse)
                    {
                        case "yes":
                            return true;

                        case "no":
                            return false;

                        default:
                            return false;
                    }

                }
                else
                {
                    Console.Clear();
                    Console.WriteLine("You've entered an invalid term");
                }
            }

            return false;
        }

        public static void DisplayInstructions()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the Dice Game!!");
            Console.WriteLine("\n\n\nThis program will simulate rolling a die and will track the frequency \neach value is rolled.");
            Console.WriteLine("\n\n\nAfter rolling the die, the program will output a summary table for the session.");
            Console.WriteLine("\n\n\nPlease press any key to continue.");
            Console.ReadKey();
            Console.Clear();
        }

        public static string getInfo(string what)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(what);
            return Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

The class I have in this is

```
using System;

namespace TripCalcApp
{
    class Dice
    {
        private int side1 = 0, side2 = 0, side3 = 0, side4 = 0, side5 = 0, side6 = 0;

        Random randNum = new Random();

        public Dice()
        {
        }

        public int Side1
        {
            get { return side1; }
            set { side1 = value; }
        }
        public int Side2
        {
            get { return side2; }
            set { side2 = value; }
        }
        public int Side3
        {
            get { return side3; }
            set { side3 = value; }
        }
        public int Side4
        {
            get { return side4; }
            set { side4 = value; }
        }
        public int Side5
        {
            get { return side5; }
            set { side5 = value; }

        }
        public int Side6
        {
            get { return side6; }
            set { side6 = value; }
        }

        public void RollDice()
        //RollDice = randNum.Next(1, 7)
        {

            switch (randNum.Next(1, 7))
            {
                case 1: side1++;
                    break;
                case 2: side2++;
                    break;
                case 3: side3++;
                    break;
                case 4: side4++;
                    break;
                case 5: side5++;
                    break;
                case 6: side6++;
                    break;
            }
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return "                          Freq. Rolls                                         " +
                "________________________________________" +
                "\nSide 1 of Die rolled     :" + side1 +
                "\nSide 2 of Die rolled     :" + side2 +
                "\nSide 3 of Die rolled     :" + side3 +
                "\nSide 4 of Die rolled     :" + side4 +
                "\nSide 5 of Die rolled     :" + side5 +
                "\nSide 6 of Die rolled     :" + side6 +
                "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

I had an idea on how to do loop it but Im still unsure. I thought of something like this but it doesnt work and I was hoping you guys could help me!!

```
        int howMany = int.Parse(getInfo("How many times would you like to roll the die?"));
        do
        {
            Dice aDice = new Dice();

            for (int counter = howMany; counter > 0; counter--)
            {
                aDice.RollDice();
            }

            while (howMany < 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(aDice);
            }
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("Session Number: {0}", sessionNumber);
            Console.WriteLine(aDice);
            playAgain = getYorN("Would you like to play again?");

            sessionNumber++;
        }
```

Comment: Please note: the back tick ` is for inline formatting. For block code formatting, indent with 4 spaces.

Comment: You are creating new dice all the time and give a new Random to each. Make it one Random at class level instead or the random numbers will not be random at all because all are created with the same timestamp as seed!! Other than that: __What__ does 'not work' and how??

Comment: Replace 6 members `side1`-`side6` with one array of 6 elements, and adjust the code to it. Instead of big switch you would have just one line, like this one `allSides[randNum.Next(0, 6)]++;`

Comment: Your title is awful ! Give most important information about the question !

Comment: That `while(howMany < 0)` loop will be infinite if the user types in a negative number.  You should just remove it.  The `for` loop looks fine though.

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is call aDice.RollDice method howMany times:

```
        while (continueRunning)
        {
            int howMany = int.Parse(getInfo("How many times do you want to roll the die?"));
            Dice aDice = new Dice();
            for(int i = 0; i < howMany; i++)
            {
                aDice.RollDice();
            }

            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("Session Number: {0}", sessionNumber);
            Console.WriteLine(aDice);

            continueRunning = getYorN("Would you like to run again?");
            sessionNumber++;
            Console.Clear();
        }
```